# How to filter two xml trees at once using XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, filter, xslt-1.0, dropdown, xfa

I'm looking for help. I'm having a XFA form (XML-based) with a dropdown, which holds a display and save value per item. As the list can be very long I'm trying to filter it using XSLT 1.0.

The source XML drom the dropdown may look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<field name="DropDownList" xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-form/2.8/">
    <!-- Displayed items to be filtered --> 
    <items xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/3.6/">
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0030</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0060</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0070</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0080</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0100</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0110</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0120</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0130</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0140</text>
    </items>
    <!-- Hidden save items to be filtered too -->
    <items save="1" presence="hidden" xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/3.6/">
        <text>item0</text>
        <text>item1</text>
        <text>item2</text>
        <text>item3</text>
        <text>item4</text>
        <text>item5</text>
        <text>item6</text>
        <text>item7</text>
        <text>item8</text>
        <text>item9</text>
    </items>
</field>
```

My current stylesheet looks this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-form/2.8/" xml:space="preserve">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <field name="DropDownList">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </field>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='field']/*[local-name()='items']" >
        <items xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/3.6/">
            <xsl:for-each select="./*[local-name()='text']">
                <xsl:if test="contains(., '01')">
                    <text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I need is the same XML structure as before to load it back into the dropdown list, but I don't found a way yet to get the second items-tree filled with the correct data. I'm thinking of using a parameter or variable to save the index of a node in the first items-tree and find the related node in the second items-tree, but how?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<field name="DropDownList" xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-form/2.8/">
    <items xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/3.6/">
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0100</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0110</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0120</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0130</text>
        <text>Lorem Ipsum 0140</text>
    </items>
    <items save="1" presence="hidden" xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/3.6/">
        <text>item5</text>
        <text>item6</text>
        <text>item7</text>
        <text>item8</text>
        <text>item9</text>
    </items>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to use mode on your templates and apply-templates.  So, add the mode attribute to the apply-templates.  And, add the mode attribute with the same name to the templates you are targeting with the apply-templates.  Then for the second output, either use a different mode, or just let it flow through without the mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. I've made another stylesheet which arleady does what I'm looking for. But, I don't think that this solution it ideal because I have to check all nodes under the first items-tree twice …

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-form/2.8/" xml:space="preserve">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="filterText" select="01"/>
    <!--Filter display items-->
    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='items'][1]/*[local-name()='text']" mode="filterDisplayItems">
        <xsl:if test="contains(., $filterText)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--Filter save items-->
    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='items'][1]/*[local-name()='text']" mode="filterSaveItems">
        <xsl:param name="nodeIndex" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:if test="contains(., $filterText)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="//*[local-name()='items'][2]/*[local-name()='text'][$nodeIndex]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <field name="ListBackup">
            <!--Create filtered list of display items-->
            <items xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/3.6/">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[local-name()='items'][1]/*[local-name()='text']" mode="filterDisplayItems"/>
            </items>
            <!--Create filtered list of save items-->
            <items save="1" presence="hidden" xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/3.6/">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[local-name()='items'][1]/*[local-name()='text']" mode="filterSaveItems"/>
            </items>
        </field>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

… which causes a performance lag in my eyes. There must be a better way. When the template that filters the first items-tree finds a match, you easily get its index with … select="position()". This should passed over to the template that filters the second items tree. There you only have to copy the nodes by there indexes then. Any Ideas how to accompish this?